# Phonegap / jQuery click callback on listview

Tags: jquery, cordova

I create dynamically a listview:

```
$('#memory_listview').append(li).promise().done(function () 
    {
        $(this).listview("refresh");

        $(this).on("click", "li", function () 
        {
            alert("click");

        });

    });
```

After a click to another button I delete the listview:

```
    $('#memory_listview').children().remove('li');
$('#memory_listview').empty();
```

If I create the listview again, I get two alerts with "click". What is wrong?

Comment: You are using event delegation `$(this).on("click", "li", function ()` try with `$("li", this).on("click",function ()` or best should be to move event handler out

Comment: Hi Satpal, thank you very much. `$("li", this).on("click",function ()` is the solution.